# Nonzero CPU% in Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, ps

I want to exclude processes with CPU=0.0 from result of `ps aux` command. Is it possible without any perversions (such as `grep`)?

Comment: Did you consider using `top` or `htop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ps aux | awk '$3!=0.0 {print}'
```

the third field that is cpu is not `0.0` will print the whole line

if you want cpu usage in `descending` order i.e high to low usage

```
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | awk '$3!=0.0 {print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use awk:

```
ps aux | awk '{if ($3 != 0.0) print $0}'
```

This will include headers since the header is != "0.0"

If you're not familiar with the syntax, this awk command will test the third element in each line (split by " " space, by default) to see if it's not "0.0". If it isn't then it will print the entire line ($0).